# Can a semiconductor device discharge power capacitors

Tags: heat, semiconductors, pulse, discharge

Trying to figure out how to discharge a capacitor yielding 75 Joule - 177v @ 4700uf. I am uncertain which or even if a semiconductor device is up to the task. Can semis do it? If yes then which can do it and do it constantly (~2x second)? How do I determine heat rise in device?

If scr's can do it please specify answers in regards to scr's.

Thank you.

Comment: Go read up on  thyristors.

Comment: Edit your question to add the 20 mOhm load. Peak currrent will then be on the order of 8000 amps.

Comment: You need to look at the capacitor ESR, the forward drop of the SCR and the load resistor. Dissipation of the stored energy will divided among the three.

Comment: So, you  need to discharge the cap 2 times per second? Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To discharge a 5000 uF capacitor in 2 seconds you need a resistor of about 400 Ohms, RC = 2.

200 V through 400 Ohms is just 0.5 A peak. Take 200 Ohms, so any 1-A transistor (in saturated mode) can discharge the capacitor with absolutely no problem, with little to no heat dissipation. The resistor might be some big one, with peak dissipation of 200 W. And the transistor should hold 200 V, which is no problem as well.

Addendum: To discharge the cap in 500 ms you need a 50-Ohm resistor, and a 4-A transistor. If you have a 20-mOhms 50-A transistor, you can do it with a 5 Ohm resistor. I would still insist on using a resistor, because it is much easier to have a resistor to dissipate power, than a transistor. I am lazy to calculate power, but I think this one will work:

[image]

Comment: Little to no heat dissipation _in the transistor_, you mean, yes?

Comment: I dont want to delay cap discharge at all my load is ~20mOhms and a resistor is unneeded.

Comment: @user186519, are you trying to make a rail gun, or something?

Comment: A sharp magnetic spike from a crossover inductor.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there are SCRs that can easily handle that, even if we assume the capacitor has zero resistance. For example [these](https://www.vishay.com/docs/93718/vs-st1280ckseries.pdf)  "hockey puck" SCRs.

Note the maximum rate of rise of current is \$10^6\$A/s. Istm is 45kA.

[image]

Of course SCRs only turn off when the current drops below the holding current, so commutation may require some consideration.

Comment: This transistor could be also up to challenge, https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/IXYS%20PDFs/VMO1600-02P.pdf It holds "only" 1.6kA, at 1.6 mOhms, so a 0.15-0.2 Ohms  "limiting" resistor better be there.